# How to add private methods to pyo3 pymethods?

Tags: python, rust, pyo3

I'd like to add hidden methods to pyo3 class methods implementation which will be invisible for Python.

Example:

```rust
#[pyclass]
pub struct SomeItem;

#[pymethods]
impl SomeItem {
    #[new]
    pub fn new() -> Self {  // visible for python constructor
        SomeItem;
    }

    pub fn method(&self) -> u8 {  // visible for python method
        self.hidden_method()
    }

    #[pyo3(ignore)]  // just for example
    fn hidden_method(&self) -> u8 {  // invisible for python method (that must be able to return non-python type)
        0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using a separate `impl` block?

```rust
#[pymethods]
impl SomeItem {
    #[new]
    pub fn new() -> Self {  // visible for python constructor
        SomeItem;
    }

    pub fn method(&self) -> u8 {  // visible for python method
        self.hidden_method()
    }
}

impl SomeItem {
    fn hidden_method(&self) -> u8 {
        0
    }
}
```

Comment: Sometimes the solution can be so simple :)